# Not able to switch between two subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to work with two subprocess.
I open the first one and send him something, then i open the second one and send him something. In both cases I send with stdin.write

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen([path], stdin = subprocess.PIPE,)
process1.stdin.write('some string1')
process2 = subprocess.Popen([path], stdin = subprocess.PIPE,)
process2.stdin.write('some string 2')
```

But when i want to send again to process1 , I do the same thing but it doesn't do nothing. 
How can I communicate with process 1 again?

Comment: now i saw that when i write to process1 again , it's actually do it in process2. why? each one have the process id no? and how can i change it?  meaning if i open two notepad , for some reason when i am tyring to write something on the first it to it on the second subprocess

Answer (score 0):

It should just work.

For example:

```
$ cat 1.py
import subprocess

process1 = subprocess.Popen("cat > file1", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process1.stdin.write('some string1\n')
process2 = subprocess.Popen("cat > file2", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process2.stdin.write('some string 2\n')
process1.stdin.write('some string3\n')
```

Afther that running the program and checking the result:

```
$ python 1.py
$ cat file1
some string1
some string3
$ cat file2
some string 2
```

So, as you can see, it just works.

Comment: now i saw that when i write to process1 again , it's actually do it in process2. why? each one have the process id no? and how can i change it?

Comment: @user3903403: What do you mean? Everything works like it should. See my example

Comment: i meant that in my code for some reason process1 actually send and write to subprocess2 and i don't know why. is it because that their path is the same?

Comment: @user3903403: It depends on the processes. What happens if you start these processes in two terminals in parallel?

Comment: i must open both from the same script

Comment: @user3903403: But it works! I've just shown it in my example. I need more info from you so I could help. I see that the code works.

Comment: you are using "cat > file1" and "cat > file2" . i open my process with the same path in both popen

Comment: @user3903403: Does my example work for you? (with cat)